# Working with listbox in winforms (c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How can i add 10 items to listbox dynamically to a listbox and after that I want to show the selected item value in click event of list box.

I tried like this

```
for(int i=1;i<10 ;i++)
{
mylistbox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

in click event handler

```
MessageBox.Show(mylistbox.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

it is showing error.

Whats the wrong with this?

Comment: What error is it showing? That's quite useful when trying to fix these sorts of problems... And before doing the MessageBox.Show, first check if there is a SelectedValue (it isn't null).

Comment: What error is being displayed?

Comment: yes it is showing null refference exception. Whats the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx) property instead.

[SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) only works when you fill the ListBox with objects and have a [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) assigned.
Here is a minimal example:

```
var mylistbox = new ListBox {Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
mylistbox.Click += (sender, e) =>
                   MessageBox.Show(mylistbox.SelectedItem.ToString());
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    mylistbox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
new Form {Controls = {mylistbox}}.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code on the click handler

MessageBox.Show(mylistbox.Text.ToString()); //This will show the selected item as your requirement.

replace the `.SelectedValue` with `.Text`

Answer (score 0):

Dmitriy has it exactly.

A good way to check what is happening when you're debugging is to highlight 'mylistbox.SelectedValue' and right-click, then select 'Add Watch'. You can then track the value of that property in the Watch window.

You can do this with any variable, and any time it shows null and you're trying to use that value you know it will throw a Null Reference Exception.

It's also good for picking up letters in a string you're trying to convert to an integer, and other similar "d'oh!" moments.